# How to set a background color for a listing?

Tags: listings, color, backgrounds

[image]
Someone who knows how to fill with  color only the box?

```
\begin{shaded} 
\begin{lstlisting}

if (a < b)
 {
    printf("A is smaller than  B!\n");
 }
 a = b;

\end{lstlisting}
\end{shaded}
```

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 6):

`listings` has a setting `backgroundcolor=\color{gray}` for this purpose:

```
\lstset{backgroundcolor=\color{gray}}
\begin{lstlisting}

if (a < b)
 {
    printf("A is smaller than  B!\n");
 }
 a = b;

\end{lstlisting}
```

See section 2.7 of the manual which you should get with `texdoc listings`.